# Button needs to have functionality of <a href= and Target=_parent

Tags: vb.net

I have a back button that uses Response.redirect, 
This opens up the page I want but in a new window instead of opening it up in the current window(refreshing to new page?)

As `<a href= Target=_self` would do ? I'm not using this as It need to be a button like the rest of the buttons.

VB.net

Answer (score -1):

Please use j query script reference and use

window.open("foo.aspx");

Comment: Intellisense doesn't pick up 'window.open .. ?